# How to compute the second degree Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ using formula for Taylor polynomial of function composition?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider the functions $$f_1(x)=x^2$$ $$f_2(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ $$f_3(x)=(f_2\circ f_1)(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

My question is about the computation of $P_{2,1,f_3}(x)$, the second-degree Taylor polynomial of $f_3$ at the point $1$, using the formula for Taylor polynomials of function compositions.

Before I get to that, let me compute this Taylor polynomial directly. We have

$$f_3'(x)=\frac{-2}{x^3}$$

$$f_3''(x)=\frac{3!}{x^4}$$

$$f_3^{(3)}(x)=\frac{4!}{x^5}$$

$$f_3^{(k)}(x)=\frac{(k+1)!}{x^{k+2}}, k\geq 3$$

Thus,

$$P_{2,1,f_3}(x)=1-2(x-1)+\frac{3!}{2}(x-1)^2$$

$$=3x^2-8x+6\tag{1}$$

Consider now the formula for computing a Taylor polynomial of a function composition

$$P_{n,a,f\circ g}(x)=[P_{n,g(a),f}(P_{n,a,g}(x))]_n$$

where $[P]_n$ denotes the truncation of polynomial $P$ to degree $n$, ie the sum of all terms of $P$ of degree $\leq n$, with $P$ written as polynomial in $x-a$.

Let's try to apply this to $f_3=f_2\circ f_1$. We have

$$P_{2,1,f_1}(x)=x^2$$

$$P_{2,1,f_2}(x)=1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2=x^2-3x+3$$

Thus, because $f_1(1)=1$, we have

$$P_{2,1,f_3}(x)=P_{2,1,f_2\circ f_1}(x)=[P_{2,1,f_2}(P_{2,1,f_1}(x))]_2$$

$$=[x^4-3x^2+3]_2\tag{2}$$

$$=3-3x^2\tag{3}$$

I would have expected $(3)$ to equal $(1)$. I am pretty sure $(1)$ is correct, because it is what Maple gives me as the Taylor polynomial of $f_3$.

**Why doesn't the application of the formula for Taylor polynomial of function composition work above?**

One possibility I see is a problem at $(2)$, the truncation. My question arose in the context of a problem in Spivak's *Calculus*, and truncation is defined with $P$ written as a polynomial in $x-a$, or in our specific case, $x-1$. $(2)$ is not written this way. I am not sure if what I just said makes sense or has any importance, but I just thought I would mention where I'm at currently.

As an addendum, I thought that we could alternatively use the formula for Taylor polynomial of a product of functions

$$P_{n,a,f\cdot g}(x)=[P_{n,a,f}(x)\cdot P_{n,a,g}(x)]_n$$

$$P_{2,1,f_3}(x)=P_{2,1,f_2\cdot f_2}(x)=[P_{2,1,f_2}(x)\cdot P_{2,1,f_2}(x)]_n$$

$$=[(x^2-3x+3)(x^2-3x+3)]_2$$

$$=[x^4-6x^3+15x^2-18x+9]_2\tag{4}$$

$$=15x^2-18x+9\tag{5}$$

which also differs from $(1)$ and $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be precisely the possibility raised in the original question: the truncation is being done incorrectly.

Starting from $(2)$ we have

$$P_{2,1,f_3}(x)=[x^4-3x^2+3]_2\tag{2}$$

$$=[g(x)]_2$$

Then

$$g(x)=P_{5,1,g}(x)=1-2 \left(x-1\right)+3 \left(x-1\right)^{2}+4 \left(x-1\right)^{3}+\left(x-1\right)^{4}$$

and

$$[g(x)]_2=1-2 \left(x-1\right)+3 \left(x-1\right)^{2}$$

$$=3x^2-8x+6\tag{1}$$

Similarly, starting from $(4)$, we have

$$P_{2,1,f_2\cdot f_2}(x)=[x^{4}-6x^{3}+15x^{2}-18x+9]_2\tag{4}$$

$$=[h(x)]_2$$

and

$$h(x)=P_{5,1,h}(x)=1-2 \left(x-1\right)+3 \left(x-1\right)^{2}-2 \left(x-1\right)^{3}+\left(x-1\right)^{4}$$

and thus

$$[h(x)]_2=1-2 \left(x-1\right)+3 \left(x-1\right)^{2}$$

$$=3x^2-8x+6\tag{1}$$

All is as it should be.